# Access struct through class instance

Tags: swift

In a `class` I created I have a `struct` called `Image`:

```
public struct Image {


 private(set) var url: String
 private(set) var crop: CGRect

    init(url: String, crop: CGRect) {
        self.url = url
        self.crop = crop
    }
}
```

I also have a function that uses`Image` as a parameter.

```
public func detectBoxes(image: Image) {
    //some code
}
```

What I want to do is access `Image` in another file to use it in a function. So, I create an instance of the `class` and try typing

```
instance.detectBoxes(image: ...)
```

BUT it won't let me create an instance of `Image` so I can use it, it just wants me to type `Class.Image` which doesn't make sense.

Does anyone know how to solve my issue? Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers,
Theo

Comment: Is your struct declared _inside_ the class declaration (i.e. a nested declaration)? Or are they just defined in the same file?

Comment: @paulvs inside the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined a nested struct inside of a class, meaning it's available from within the class context.

If you wish to just use an instance of type `Image` and not `<ClassName>.Image` you must move the declaration of the struct out side the scope of the class.

Comment: thanks so much! I did what you suggested but when I try to make an instance of it in my other file by doing `var imageInstance = Image(` it doesn't autocomplete to be `Image(url: String, crop: CGRect)`. Do you know what's up with that. Once I get that working I'm golden. I'll definitely give you the check mark if you can fix that

Comment: i realized that my `init()` function wasn't public, so I made it so, but it still doesn't work. I'm getting the error when I type `var imageInstace = Image(url: "blah", crop: "blah")`, *'Image' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level*

Comment: Just an observation, you don't have to declare "default" init for structs, only classes. If you write`struct A { var x = 0 }` it automatically has a `A(x: Int)` init.